# how to emulate "replace a b b a" with a sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed, replace, tr

I am trying to emulate a replace command which swaps two characters, with a sed script,
but the obvious choice:

```
sed -e 's/a/b/g' -e 's/b/a/g'
```

does no work. Can you point me how to do it correctly?

Comment: Since none of the answers say so, I'll just note here that your attempt isn't working because you're first swapping every `a` to `b` and then swapping every `b` to `a`. So `aaabbb` would go `aaabbb --> bbbbbb --> aaaaaa`. `sed` runs its commands in sequence, rather than all at once.

Answer (score 12):

If you only want to replace individual *characters*, not longer strings, use

```
sed -e 'y/ab/ba/'
```

or the equivalent `tr` command from X Tian's answer. For arbitrary strings, you have to work harder:

If there is any character that does certainly not occur in the input, such as `#` (even a control character will do), you can use something like

```
sed -e 's/a/#/g;s/b/a/g;s/#/b/g;'
```

Alternatively, you can do some tricks with prefixing:

```
sed -e '
s/a/xa/g;
s/b/xb/g;
s/xa/yb/g;
s/xb/ya/g;
s/ya/a/g;
s/yb/b/g;
'
```

that is: prefix every `a` and `b` with `x` (which means: not yet modified), replace `xa` by `yb` and vice versa (where `y` means: modified), and remove all prefixes.

Comment: Nice prefixing trick!

Answer (score 12):

I would use translate command *tr* eg.

```
tr ab ba < input_file
```

Comment: thanks X Tian. Is there any advantages of using 'tr ab ba' over 'replace a b b a' ?

Comment: @Mitten you're the one who specifically asked for a non `replace` solution, you tell us :).

Comment: The advantage for me is that I have the tr command and know it but not the replace command. If I've answered you question could you please tick it. tks

Answer (score 2):

If you have a spare character you can do the suggestion of Uwe.

If you really only need to replace a single character and you do not necessarily need `sed`, use `tr` as suggested by XTian.

If you don't need `sed` and you might replace longer sequences without needing a spare character you might go with something like that:

```
perl -le '%ex=(a=>"b",b=>"a"); $keys=join("|",keys(%ex)); $text="abba"; $text=~s/$keys/$ex{$&}/eg; print $text'
```

or

```
ruby -e 'ex={"a"=>"b","b"=>"a"}; puts "abba".gsub(/(#{ex.keys.join("|")})/,ex)'
```